# bug on module re in python (backreference)?

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I want to match:

> first second

and

> second first

so the regular expression:

```
re.match(r'(?:(?P<f>first) (?P<s>second)|(?P=s) (?P=f))', 'first second')
```

matches, but this one:

```
re.match(r'(?:(?P<f>first) (?P<s>second)|(?P=s) (?P=f))', 'second first')
```

does not matches. Is this a bug on backreference in A|B ?

Comment: When in doubt, do *not* blame the regular expression engine; it rarely is a bug in the engine.

Comment: That's ok of course, but if you try it doesn't work, documentation does not report anything about that, and the syntax is right to me. so if you find the problem anywhere else you're right

Comment: There is more information about backreferences in the "Groups" section of the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496).

Comment: @aliteralmind: the FAQ doesn't (yet) have any *proper* references for backreferences; the best that's there now is a specific phone-number pattern that doesn't say much about how they work.

Comment: Hm. Okay. Then perhaps I'll look around for better ones, and please let me know if you find (or create!  :) any...or feel free to add them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
(?=.*(?P<f>first))(?=.*(?P<s>second))
```

`(?=...)` is a positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) it assumes that the word `first` is present somewhere in the string without making it part of the match (it's a zero length assertion). It's the same for `second`.

This regex is true if there is `first` and `second` in any order in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood how backreferences *work*. For a backreference to match anything, the *original* reference must have matched *too*.

In your second example, the `(?P<f>first)` group didn't match anything, so the `(?P=f)` back reference cannot match anything either.

Back references are the wrong tool here; you'll have to repeat at least one of your groups, literally:

```
r'(?:(?P<f>first )?(?P<s>second)(?(f)| first))'
```

would use a conditional pattern that only matches `first` after `second` if there was no `f` match before `second`:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(?P<f>first )?(?P<s>second)(?(f)$| first))')
>>> pattern.match('first second').group()
'first second'
>>> pattern.match('second first').group()
'second first'
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Do you have any idea of doing that (first second|second first) without making copy/paste in the regex?